# Python_Calculative coordinates for labels in Plotly lib

Tags: python, pandas, label, position, plotly

In the code below I have marker's labels on the map itself.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

rows=[['501-600','15','122.58333','45.36667'],
      ['till 500','4','12.5','27.5'],
      ['more 1001','41','-115.53333','38.08'],
      ]

colmns=['bins','data','longitude','latitude']
df=pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=colmns)
df = df.astype({"data": int})

fig=px.scatter_geo(df,lon='longitude', lat='latitude',
                      color='bins',
                      opacity=0.5,
                      size='data',
                      projection="natural earth")

fig.update_traces(hovertemplate ='bins')

fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(lon=[float(d) + 5 for d in df["longitude"]],
              lat=[float(d) + 0 for d in df["latitude"]],
              text=df["data"],
              textposition="middle right",
              mode='text',
              showlegend=False))
fig.show()
```

I put this piece of code:

```
float(d) + 5 for d in df["longitude"]],
lat=[float(d) + 0 for d in df["latitude"]]
```

to make these labels close to the markers.
[image]
But in case of resizing of map these labels looks weird.
[image: Length between marker and it's label too big.]
I believe that it is possible to put into condition of labels position not only absolute values
as it is now, but some sort of dependency between labels coordinates and values in data.

Comment: is `textposition="center" ` an option?  use `sizeref`, like `fig.update_traces(marker_sizeref=.025)` if the smallest marker is too small to fit the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method that might work for you is padding your `df.data` values with spaces.  For example here the data is padded with three spaces in the new variable `tag`.

```py
# tag = ['   15', '   4', '   41']
tag = "   " + df['data'].astype(str)

fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(lon=df["longitude"],
              lat=df["latitude"],
              text = tag,
              textposition="middle right",
              mode='text',
              showlegend=False))
```

or using `texttemplate`:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(lon=df["longitude"],
              lat=df["latitude"],
              text=df["data"],
              textposition="middle right",
              mode='text',
              showlegend=False,
              texttemplate="   %{text}"
                           ))
```

UPDATE: further formatting can be done with `texttemplate` by specifying a variable width based on `df.data` and using right justification, see  [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for more options.  Something like:

```py
#text template width based on formula width=x/12+3 and '>' to right justify
tt = ["%{text:>" + str(x/12 + 3) + "}" for x in df['data']]

fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(lon=df["longitude"],
              lat=df["latitude"],
              text=df["data"],
              textposition="middle right",
              mode='text',
              showlegend=False,
              texttemplate= tt
                           ))
```

original:

[image]

zoomed:

[image]

Comment: It is interesting option, but I think that there should be possible to use dependency with size of the cirlce within %, coz all sizes diffenent and when you zoomed it's much more visible. Figures should be at the same distance of the center of marker/border of marker.